# Paste text into sam editor from an external application

Tags: ed, plan9

I am running the editor sam as a standalone application on Linux. I am using this version:

```
git clone https://github.com/9fans/plan9port plan9
```

So far I have not been able to figure out a way to paste text into the *bitmap* display from an external Linux application. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Sam has its own cut-and-paste buffer separate from the OS. To swap sam's and the OS's, you use the middle-button  menu item. (rio is the name of the window system it is swapping buffers with on Plan 9.)"

https://github.com/9fans/plan9port/issues/510#issuecomment-882111831